# Is there any way to generate PDF file from a XML/HTML template in iOs

Tags: ios, xml, ipad, pdf-generation

I am creating an iPad application, in that i have to use different PDF forms. I got some methods to generate PDF files through code using Quartz2D. But I have to write entire forms through code. I may have to update the PDF forms in future, so again I have to write the code. So I heard that there is a component called iTextSharp for .net pdf creation - is there something similar for iOS? So that I can use some XML templates to create the PDF files. 
Please help, thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I do this in my app using the iOS print subsystem and the UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter.  The trick is to write your own custom UIPrintPageRenderer that overrides and returns correct values from paperRect and numberOfPages.  You'll add your UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(s) to your custom UIPrintPageRenderer.

Then, you'll need routines similar to this, in the context of your custom UIPrintPageRenderer:

```
- (CGRect) paperRect
{
    if (!_generatingPdf)
        return [super paperRect];

    return UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();
}

- (CGRect) printableRect
{
    if (!_generatingPdf)
        return [super printableRect];

    return CGRectInset( self.paperRect, 20, 20 );
}

- (NSData*) printToPDF
{
    _generatingPdf = YES;

    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 612), nil );  // letter-size, landscape

    [self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

    CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages ; i++ )
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        [self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    _generatingPdf = NO;

//    NSString* filename = @"/Volumes/Macintosh HD 2/test.pdf";
//    [pdfData writeToFile: filename  atomically: YES];

    return pdfData;
}
```

Comment: are you generating the PDF files from an XML template?

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life!By the way,is this method allowed by app store?

Comment: @ChenXin; I have an app approved using this technique.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot ! This is a great way to create PDF files, much better and easier than with core graphics.

Comment: @TomSwift Did you manage to render images as well using this technique ? I tried several options (custom NSURLProtocol, local file URL, base64 image embedding) and nothing seems to work... Any help on that ?

Comment: @nicholasthenoz.  I haven't tried.  Have you tried an image from your bundle, per this example?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058556/how-to-add-images-in-uimarkuptextprintformatter

Comment: @TomSwift Yeah I tried that and it actually works if you print the document using UIPrintInteractionController. But if you use your code to print, no image is ever rendered... I also tried defining a custom url protocol (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572258/ios-webview-remote-html-with-local-image-files), but same issue, as well as direct embedding of the images in base64 encoding... I really can't get my head around this... The UIPrintInteractionController must call some hidden method I don't see

Comment: @nicolasthenoz did you end up figuring it out?

Comment: Is this solution still functional? My subclassed page renderer never receives calls for printableRect or paperRect and I end up with blank PDF pages.

Comment: @JackLawrence Well I did not succeed using a UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter so I tweaked it a little bit. I added a webview to my custom UIPrintPageRenderer, created a function which takes the html as a parameter and calls [UIWebView loadHTMLString:baseURL:]. Once the webview has finished loading, I add its viewPrintFormatter to the renderer and call printToPDF. Not the best method but it works, but you have to call it on the main thread as it is using a UI element.

Comment: @nicolasthenoz Oooh interesting. `-[UIWebView viewPrintFormatter]` always returns 0 for `pageCount`, so by combining the method above with `viewPrintFormatter` you were able to provide a page count etc and still use the built in formatter. I'll try it out.

Comment: can someone give me the complete coding to convert html to pdf ? I need it very badly

Comment: hi I have got one requirement that i have to load one html file and that html file will have text fields, labels, check box buttons etc. I have to get the data whatever user will enter and then i have to convert it into pdf with user enter data.

Comment: @TomSwift I used this method.Everything is fine .But the text text is getting broken in between the pages.Is there any way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

@TomSwift : agree with his answer but i would like to explain in better way

### To be able create `PDF` from `UIWebView` is load HTML to yourWebView or there might be case yourWebView can also be hidden to generate PDF but process remains the same

#### 1) Added `Category` of `UIPrintPageRenderer` for getting PDF Data as yourWebView.viewPrintFormatter need to be used

```
@interface UIPrintPageRenderer (PDF)
- (NSData*) printToPDF;
@end

@implementation UIPrintPageRenderer (PDF)
- (NSData*) printToPDF
{
  NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, self.paperRect, nil );
  [self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];
  CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();
  for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages ; i++ )
  {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    [self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];
  }
  UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
  return pdfData;
}
@end
```

#### 2) Add these define for A4 size or any custom size you want

```
#define kPaperSizeA4 CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8)
```

#### 3) Process how we can create PDF

```
//create print renderer
UIPrintPageRenderer *render = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
[render addPrintFormatter:yourWebView.viewPrintFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];

//provide padding ---- increase these values according to your requirement
float topPadding = 10.0f;
float bottomPadding = 10.0f;
float leftPadding = 10.0f;
float rightPadding = 10.0f;

//provide rect for printing and for actual PDF Rect of page
CGRect printableRect = CGRectMake(leftPadding,
                                  topPadding,
                                  kPaperSizeA4.width-leftPadding-rightPadding,
                                  kPaperSizeA4.height-topPadding-bottomPadding);
CGRect paperRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, kPaperSizeA4.width, kPaperSizeA4.height);
[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:paperRect] forKey:@"paperRect"];
[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:printableRect] forKey:@"printableRect"];

//category created above is used here 
NSData *pdfData = [render printToPDF];
//Save PDF to directory for usage
if (pdfData) {
  [pdfData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tmp.pdf",NSTemporaryDirectory()] atomically: YES];
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"PDF couldnot be created");
}
```

Comment: I am using the same technique. but if i set left and right paddings > 0 then images in HTML are cutting from right side. Any suggestion....???

Comment: @san : Above words meant a lot to me rather than upvotes. You are welcome

Comment: @PareshNavadiya I used this method.Everything is fine .But the text text is getting broken in between the pages.Is there any way to fix it.