# How to set bottom space in pdf when create a PDF file from an HTML string in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, space, bottom-type

Following the example as below URL.

https://gist.github.com/nyg/b8cd742250826cb1471f

It is a great example for me if can set bottom space more perfect.

Comment: Did you try changing the values in CGRectInset?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of test and search with any possible, 
I find this theme ( 
[Is there any way to generate PDF file from a XML/HTML template in iOs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528658/is-there-any-way-to-generate-pdf-file-from-a-xml-html-template-in-ios)) 
and revise some codes as below:

```
//let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8); // A4, 72 dpi    
let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 575.2, height: 821.8); // A4, 72 dpi
..
..
..
//UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) , nil);
```